# Displaying columns and rows in grid format. MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, sql, grid

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this for a while now and I can't work it out at all.

```
product_column   product_row    product_name
__________________________________________________
1                1              product_1
1                2              product_2
1                3              product_3
2                1              product_4
2                2              product_5
2                3              product_6
3                1              product_7
3                2              product_8
3                3              product_9
4                1              product_10
4                2              product_11
4                3              product_12
```

That's a snippet of the table, what I'm trying to establish is a grid-like display of the products, where the product_columns are parent divs and the product_rows in these columns are child divs, like below;

```
<div class = "parent">
   <div class = "child">
      product_1
   </div>
   <div class = "child">
      product_2
   </div>
   <div class = "child">
      product_3
   </div>
</div>
<div class = "parent">
   <div class = "child">
      product_4
   </div>
   <div class = "child">
      product_5
   </div>
   <div class = "child">
     product_6
   </div>
</div>
```

Like I say I've been plugging away it for quite a while now and I've hit a stumbling block. The number of columns is not a set number either.

Thank you in advance for any help I receive.

Comment: How are you actually getting this data from your database?

Comment: I am getting the data via SQL queries

Comment: how could the number of columns in a db table not be a set ?

Comment: Not in the database table, I mean the product_column field will be updated regularly so there could be 20 or 200.

Comment: updated where ... in the database ?

Comment: @user3339243 - I could guess that you were getting the data from your database using SQL queries: what query are you using?

Comment: Okay sorry I don't think I've been very clear. Products will be added to and removed from the database regularly and this means that they'll be assigned a 'product_column' and 'product_row' so there won't a fixed amount of 'product columns'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the products that belongs to a column in an array with the same index, something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT product_column, product_row, product_name FROM table";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$products = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $products[$row['product_column']][] = $row;
}
```

And to iterate trough this array you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product_column => $list_products) {
  echo "<div class='parent'>";
    foreach($list_products as $product){
      echo "<div class='child'>".$product['product_name']."</div>";
    }  
  echo "</div>";
}
```